# Programming terminology: Expression statements in Russian

Tags: перевод

В разных языках программирования есть понятия "expression" и "statement". "Expression" тривиально переводится на русский как "выражение": Со "statement"-ом дела чуть посложнее, но кажется, техническая литература остановилась на термине "инструкция", который неплохо подходит.

В стандарте языка C++ есть еще и понятие "expression statement", которое означает что-то типа "инструкция, выраженная выражением". Так как я очень давно уже не читаю техническую литературу на русском, я не имею понятия, имеет ли данный термин общепринятый перевод.

Идеальным вариантом будет, если кто знает перевод термина "expression statement". Но если нет, помогите придумать перевод этому термину. В частности, если в русском языке есть прилагательное от слова "выражение", то оно, думаю, может подойти.

P.S. Для технарей, кто не в курсе: "a = b + c" - выражение, "a = b + c;" - инструкция, а точнее expression statement.

Comment: А просто слово "инструкция" не подойдет?

Comment: @Dmitry: Просто "инструкция" слишком общее понятие. Есть условная инструкция, инструкция объявления, инструкция return, и т.д. Вариант kotlomoy отлично подходит

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Словарь](http://www.multitran.ru/c/m.exe?t=6491843_1_2&s1=expression%20statement) предлагает такие варианты:
`оператор-выражение`, `команда-выражение`, `инструкция-выражение`, `оператор выражения`.

Лично я склоняюсь к второму или третьему варианту. Не нравится мне перевод `statement`->`оператор` из-за путаницы с арифметическими и др. операторами.

Answer (score 3):

There is the official translation of Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ book and it is better that we all use the Russian terminology used there instead of introducing new translations of terms (even if some translations may feel awkward :-)).

Here is an excerpt from the translated book followed by the same excerpt from the original:

```
Все такие неоднозначности разрешаются в пользу объявлений (если нечто выглядит
как объявление, это и есть объявление). Например:

Т(а)->т ;       // оператор-выражение
Т(а)++;         // оператор-выражение
Т(*е)(int(3));  // объявление
T(f)[4]         // объявление
Т(а);           // объявление
Т(а)=m;         // объявление
```

Бьерн Страуструп. Язык программирования C++. Специальное издание. Пер. с англ. — М.:Издательство Бином, 2011 г. ISBN 978-5-7989-0425-9 (pyc.), стр. 934.

---

```
    All such ambiguities are resolved to declarations. That is, "if it could possibly be 
interpreted as a declaration, it is a declaration." 
For example:

    T(a)->m;      // expression statement
    T(a)++;       // expression statement
    T(*e)(int(3));// declaration
    T(f)[4];      // declaration
    T(a);         // declaration
    T(a)=m;       // declaration
```

The C++ Programming Language. Third Edition. Bjarne Stroustrup. AT&T Labs
Murray Hill, New Jersey 1997. p. 802.

In conclusion:

- *statement* is translated as *оператор*
- *expression statement* is translated as *оператор-выражение*
- (by the way) *operator* is translated as *операция*

Answer (score 1):

Из уроков Java

- Assignment expressions
- Any use of ++ or --
- Method invocations
- Object creation expressions

Such statements are called expression statements.

Выходит пример a = b + c - это составное выражение (присвоение и вычисление).
А выражения-инструкции (я так перевел):

int i = 0;
i++;
using(i);
String str = new String("");

Answer (score -6):

экспрешн-стэйтмент (I know C++, Russian and English, unlike the other poster)

Comment: As it stands, this answer is not very good. Would you care provide any citations from literature, where элрпешн-стейтмент is used?